# Getting read only file errors when using npn install jade for a node js project

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am using Ubuntu (latest version downloaded) and node js (again latest version downloaded) on a Virtual Box. I have shared a folder where in Ubuntu I am trying to install jade in it.

But I keep getting this error

> This is most likely not a problem with npm itself and is related to the file system being read-only. Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems.

I get the same error when I try creating a new project using WebStorm too. Earlier this used to work, somehow not this is not working. Any advice ?